# BoxCox transformation (forecast package)

Tags: r, data-transformation, tbats

This is a continue of the question asked at [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfcsp.png). `BoxCox.lambda` function of *forecast package* gives different lambda values for different lower and upper bounds and also again gives different lambda values if the passed object is a time-series (`ts`) object. Mr. Hyndman explained difference in ts object as `BoxCox.lambda` takes seasonality into account and TBATS uses a different method to calculate lambda.

I created a simple `myboxcox` transformation and and `find_lambda` functions and compared them in the following code sample.

[image]

Default lower and upper limits of `BoxCox.lambda` function gives `-1` and if the bounds are `-2` and `2`, gives `lambda1 = -1.6013`. Clearly, `lambda1` is not a good transformation coefficient as seen in the plot above. `method = 'loglike'` gives `lambda2 = 0` and TBATS gives `lambda3 = 0.01284`. `find_lambda` function uses a log-likelihood approach and result is very close to TBATS one. At least, for the `BoxCox.lambda(t, "loglik", -2, 2)`, I expect to find a result close to TBATS' one.

So, Is this a bug? or am I missing something here?

According to this, If I want to transform my data before TBATS for some reason, I have to run TBATS first, find the proper lambda value for TBATS and transform my data before re-run TBATS. Also somebody usually expects transformed data should conform to a normal distribution but as seen here, it's not.

```
library(forecast)
myboxcox <- function(x, lambda = 0) {
  if (lambda == 0) log(x) else (x^lambda - 1)/lambda
}
find_lambda <- function(x, interval = seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.00001)) {
  n <- length(x)
  l <- sapply(interval, function(i) {
    tt <- myboxcox(x, i)
    v <- sum((tt - mean(tt))^2)/n
    -(n/2) * log(v) + (i - 1) * sum(log(x))
  })
  return(interval[which.max(l)])
}

set.seed(1)
y <- rlnorm(3000)
t <- msts(y, seasonal.periods = c(24, 168))
bounds <- matrix(c(-2, -1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1.5), ncol = 2)
a <- cbind(bounds, apply(bounds, 1, function(x) BoxCox.lambda(t, lower = x[1], upper = x[2])))
a <- cbind(a, apply(bounds, 1, function(x) BoxCox.lambda(y, lower = x[1], 
                                           upper = x[2])))
colnames(a) <- c("lambda_min", "lambda_max", "ts", "vector")
print(a)
#      lambda_min lambda_max            ts        vector
# [1,]         -2        2.0 -1.601259e+00 -1.535313e-01
# [2,]         -1        2.0 -9.999242e-01 -1.535165e-01
# [3,]          0        1.0  6.610696e-05  6.610696e-05
# [4,]          0        1.5  5.847034e-05  5.847034e-05

tb <- tbats(t)
cat("tbats_lambda: ", as.numeric(tb$lambda))
# tbats_lambda:  0.01284863

lambda1 <- BoxCox.lambda(t, lower = -2, upper = 2) # -1.6013
lambda2 <- BoxCox.lambda(t, "loglik", -2, 2) # 0
lambda3 <- tb$lambda # 0.01284
lambda4 <- find_lambda(y) # 0.01028

tt1 <- BoxCox(t, lambda1)
tt2 <- BoxCox(t, lambda2)
tt3 <- BoxCox(t, lambda3)
tt4 <- myboxcox(y, lambda4)

op <- par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
plot(density(t), main = "original")
plot(density(tt1), main = "lambda1")
plot(density(tt2), main = "lambda2")
plot(density(tt3), main = "lambda3")
plot(density(tt4), main = "lambda4")
par(op)

shapiro.test(tt1)
shapiro.test(tt2)
shapiro.test(tt3)
shapiro.test(tt4)
```

1- https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/834

Answer (score 2):

"Also somebody usually expects transformed data should conform to a normal distribution but as seen here, it's not." Somebody is ill informed and needs to read the fine print. Normality is not the objective here .. decoupling the relationship between the expected value and the error variance is the objective premised on no outliers , no level shifts , no changes in model parameters over time , no deterministic change points in error variance ... .

Care should be taken to evaluate transformation using residuals not the original data as the original data might be flawed by anomalies or other Gaussian Violations. See [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers) for more .